# Insert space before tag except when at the beginning of a line

Tags: css

How can I put some extra space before a tag in all cases *except* when the tag is at the beginning of a line?

Example:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="spaced">consectetur adipiscing</span> 
elit. Proin eleifend massa est, a fringilla erat tempor nec. </p>
```

Essentially, I would like to do

```
.spaced {
  padding-left: 0.25em;
}
```

except that if `consectetur` is at the beginning of the line, it doesn't line up with the rest of the paragraph:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can wrap the previous word with `span.spaced` and use `margin-right` instead ;)

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yuoEv

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean, I put it in JSFiddle and it looks fine from what you're telling me.
[Like so](http://jsfiddle.net/PPR6P/1/)

```
  It required me to put code for the link.
```

Comment: Shrink the window until consectetur is the first word in a line and see what I mean.